# How can I order my items by date and time with this convoluted table structure?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am using an awful propriety CMS system.

Its events module can store events by an explicit date/time, e.g. `2011-08-04 13:30:00` or by a weekly recurring event, of which the recurring day is stored as a 0 based integer and the time is added to the date/time field (where the data is 0), e.g. `0000-00-00 13:30:00`.

I need to get all events upcoming in the next 2 weeks. This means I need *all* weekly recurring events and the explicit dates which fall in the next 2 weeks.

I'm not much of an SQL expert. I wrote this query...

```
SELECT `id`,
       `name`,
       `info`,
       `date_time`,
       `weekly_day`
FROM   `events` AS a
WHERE  `active` = true
       AND `id` IN (SELECT `id`
                    FROM   `events`
                    WHERE  WEEK(`date_time`) BETWEEN WEEK(NOW()) AND WEEK(
                                                     DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL
                                                     1 WEEK)))
        OR DATE(`date_time`) = 0
ORDER  BY Time_to_sec(IF(TIME(`date_time`), TIME(`date_time`),
                                            Concat(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM `date_time`
                                                   ), ":",
                                            EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM `date_time`)))),
          IF(DATE(`date_time`), Dayofweek(`date_time`), `weekly_day` + 1) ASC
```

(Note that the `NOW()` above are replaced with some PHP with echoes the current date in the MySQL format. The MySQL server's timezone is different to the timezone I want.)

This successfully gets all records I want, but it doesn't order them correctly. For example, events on the 9th June are appearing before events on the 2nd June.

How can I fix my query?

Cheers.

### Update

I've came up with this but I am still stuck... it won't display the weekly events despite the dates appearing to be correct.

```
SELECT `id`,
       `name`,
       `info`,
       `date_time`,
       `weekly_day`,
       ( DATE(`date_time`) = 0 ) AS `weekly`
FROM   `events`
WHERE  `active` = true
       AND IF (DATE(`date_time`), WEEK(`date_time`),
           DATE_ADD(
               Concat(DATE(NOW()), " ", Concat(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM `date_time`),
                                        ":",
                                        EXTRACT
                                        (
                                        MINUTE FROM `date_time`))), INTERVAL
           `weekly_day`
                                                                    DAY))
           BETWEEN WEEK(
           NOW()) AND WEEK(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK))
ORDER  BY `date_time` ASC
```

I couldn't use `TIME()` to extract the time portion because it kept returning `NULL`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it in two steps:

1. Convert the recurring entries into the two DATETIME values for the next two weeks.  This would be one sub-query.
2. Collect the non-recurring entries from the same period.  This would be a second sub-query.

The UNION of the two sub-queries gives you all the events with their actual date and time of occurrence; it is trivial to order that correctly.

If you need to record whether or not the information is from a recurring meeting, keep something (probably a simple 'R' or 'N') in the select-list of the two sub-queries so you can tell whether the original entry was recurring or non-recurring.

---

I'm not an expert in MySQL DATETIME manipulation - but I do know my away around that area of another DBMS, namely Informix.  For my purposes in this discussion, there are only two interesting columns in the table: `date_time` and `weekly_day`.  I assume that you are using the MySQL convention that 1 = Sunday, 7 = Saturday.  Since we need 2 weeks' worth of information for recurring events, it is probably easiest to generate 3 weeks and to filter out the irrelevant ones.

Given a reference date and an integer day of the week, we can get three values from it using:

```
 refdate - DAYOFWEEK(refdate) + day_of_week
 refdate - DAYOFWEEK(refdate) + day_of_week + INTERVAL  7 DAYS
 refdate - DAYOFWEEK(refdate) + day_of_week + INTERVAL 14 DAYS
```

These yield three dates; the first might be in the past or the third might be too far in the future (and hence need discarding).  This is the arithmetic when dates are a count of days since a reference date (as in Informix).  To translate the third line into MySQL, assuming 'refdate' is `NOW()`, we seem to have to write (extraordinarily verbosely - I thought Informix was badly verbose for DATETIME manipulation):

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), DAYOFWEEK(NOW())), INTERVAL weekly_day DAY),
    INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

Here, I'm assuming that I can cast the integer in `weekly_day` to a number of days; adjust if necessary.  These formulae give three DATE values for each of the recurring entries, of which two are relevant.  To add the time, I think we need:

```
DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), DAYOFWEEK(NOW())), INTERVAL weekly_day DAY),
    INTERVAL 14 DAY), INTERVAL TIME(date_time) HOUR_SECOND)
```

So, the first sub-query mentioned in my initial answer itself needs to be a 3-way UNION.

```
SELECT 'R' AS info_mode,
       DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), DAYOFWEEK(NOW())),
                                  INTERVAL weekly_day DAY),
                         INTERVAL 14 DAY),
                INTERVAL TIME(date_time) HOUR_SECOND) AS event_time
  FROM events
UNION
SELECT 'R' AS info_mode,
       DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), DAYOFWEEK(NOW())),
                                  INTERVAL weekly_day DAY),
                         INTERVAL 7 DAY),
                INTERVAL TIME(date_time) HOUR_SECOND) AS event_time
  FROM events
UNION
SELECT 'R' AS info_mode,
       DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), DAYOFWEEK(NOW())),
                                  INTERVAL weekly_day DAY),
                INTERVAL TIME(date_time) HOUR_SECOND) AS event_time
  FROM events;
```

You now need to filter that for 'the next two weeks'.  Which date/time range is that, exactly?  From the reference moment - designated NOW()?  Or from the beginning of the reference day?  Or from the beginning of the day after the reference day?  All could be plausible; since the code appears to use the reference mode (and it is simplest), we'll go with that:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 'R' AS info_mode,
               DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), DAYOFWEEK(NOW())),
                                          INTERVAL weekly_day DAY),
                                 INTERVAL 14 DAY),
                        INTERVAL TIME(date_time) HOUR_SECOND) AS event_time
          FROM events
        UNION
        SELECT 'R' AS info_mode,
               DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), DAYOFWEEK(NOW())),
                                          INTERVAL weekly_day DAY),
                                 INTERVAL 7 DAY),
                        INTERVAL TIME(date_time) HOUR_SECOND) AS event_time
          FROM events
        UNION
        SELECT 'R' AS info_mode,
               DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), DAYOFWEEK(NOW())),
                                          INTERVAL weekly_day DAY),
                        INTERVAL TIME(date_time) HOUR_SECOND) AS event_time
          FROM events) AS r
  WHERE r.event_time BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```

This gives the recurring events.  The filter condition on `r.event_time` could be pushed down (replicated) in each branch of the UNION, but I'll leave it where it is, pro tempore.

The non-recurring events are found using:

```
SELECT 'N' AS info_mode,
       date_time AS event_time
  FROM events AS e
 WHERE e.date_time BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
   AND DATE(e.date_time) != DATE '0000-00-00';
```

Hence, we can create the union of those two queries.  It is possible to drag the condition on `event_time` out of the two sub-queries (and we can hope that the optimizer then 'puts it back').
And the non-recurring events sub-query simply becomes the fourth part of a UNION, leading to:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 'R' AS info_mode,
               DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), DAYOFWEEK(NOW())),
                                          INTERVAL weekly_day DAY),
                                 INTERVAL 14 DAY),
                        INTERVAL TIME(date_time) HOUR_SECOND) AS event_time
          FROM events
        UNION
        SELECT 'R' AS info_mode,
               DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), DAYOFWEEK(NOW())),
                                          INTERVAL weekly_day DAY),
                                 INTERVAL 7 DAY),
                        INTERVAL TIME(date_time) HOUR_SECOND) AS event_time
          FROM events
        UNION
        SELECT 'R' AS info_mode,
               DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(NOW(), DAYOFWEEK(NOW())),
                                          INTERVAL weekly_day DAY),
                        INTERVAL TIME(date_time) HOUR_SECOND) AS event_time
          FROM events
        UNION
        SELECT 'N' AS info_mode,
               date_time AS event_time
          FROM events
         WHERE DATE(e.date_time) != DATE '0000-00-00'
       ) AS e
 WHERE e.event_time BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY);
```

So, that should give you the list of event types (recurring, non-recurring) and the ones that occur in the next 14 days.  You just need to add back the `id`, `name` and `info` columns (plus, for debugging, the raw `date_time` and `weekly_day` columns) to each of the 4 queries in the UNION, and an ORDER BY clause on `e.event_time` (and any tie-breaking columns you want to add).

Please be kind about any syntax or DBMS-specific semantic errors; I hope the concept is clear (and correct), even if there are details that are not correct because of unfamiliarity with the details of MySQL.